# Installation of Perl6 fails, no registered operation handler

Tags: raku

I'm trying to install Perl6 thus:

```
perl Configure.pl --backend=jvm --gen-nqp
```

and then the traditional `make` & `make install`

the latter-most of which gives this error:

```
== Installing modules for JVM
cd modules/zef && sh -c "PATH='/illumina/runs/Scripts/perl6/rakudo-star-2018.10/install/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/illumina/runs/RNASeq/stringtie-1.3.3b.Linux_x86_64:/illumina/runs/RNASeq/subread-1.6.0-Linux-x86_64/bin:/illumina/runs/RNASeq/STAR-master/bin/Linux_x86_64:/illumina/runs/RNASeq/hisat2-2.1.0:/home/703404669/Scripts/vcftools-vcftools-ea875e2/src/cpp:/illumina/runs/RNASeq/FastQC:/home/703404669/.local/bin:/home/703404669/bin' /illumina/runs/Scripts/perl6/rakudo-star-2018.10/install/bin/perl6-j -Ilib bin/zef install ."
===SORRY!===
Error while compiling op nativecallinvoke, no registered operation handler
make: *** [modules-install-j] Error 1
```

I am still a newbie with Perl6, I have no idea how to deal with this error, and it doesn't show up on search engines.

How can I get past this error to install perl6?

Comment: I years ago quit paying attention to the JVM backend but I just took a quick look for you. Here's the [Rakudo issue queue with JVM tag](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=is%3Aissue+label%3AJVM+). I don't see a global "JVM backend is broken for everyone" issue. Last Rakudo and NQP source mentions of "nativecallinvoke" are from August 2017 and [last #perl6 IRC channel mention a month later](https://colabti.org/irclogger/irclogger_log/perl6?date=2017-09-21#l840). I recommend you focus on MoarVM as per liz's answer and my comment on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The JVM backend has not received quite the amount of love that the MoarVM backend has and is known to have problems (although I'm surprised to see it is this bad).

Is there a reason why you would not like to use the MoarVM backend?  If you don't have a reason, you could try changing the `--backend=jvm` parameter to `--gen-moar`, which would then fetch and build the MoarVM backend for you automagically.

Comment: moarVM failed at first, java was my 2nd choice after that failure :/

Comment: Hi @con. It's pretty much guaranteed that, perhaps with some patience required, we'll be able to get MoarVM working on whatever system you have (unless you're trying to run it on some bizarre system from another galaxy). To add to liz's points, the only backend that's officially "production" status is MoarVM. It works well. In contrast the JVM backend is officially "experimental", and I'd say that's generous. Please focus on MoarVM and forget the JVM backend. Please start another SO with what went wrong when trying to install MoarVM, and include your system details, and we can go from there.